# Sending an asp.net dynamic variable to a jQuery function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an input that gets its value from code behind. Now I want to send that same variable to a jQuery function using ValidateUploadPhoto(). Is that possible? If Yes then how?

```
<input type="text" ID="inputID" value="<%= UploadStatus %>" />

<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload_status" class="FileUpload" runat="server" onchange="ValidateUploadPhoto();" />

function ValidateUploadPhoto(UploadStatus) 
{
 // Do stuff based on the value of UploadStatus
}
```

Comment: You have stored value in inputID is it not getting value ?

Comment: Yes I'm getting a value and I want to send that same value to a jQuery function...

Comment: than simply use it in function by accessing value from input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that variable in your function directly.

```
function ValidateUploadPhoto() 
{
  var  UploadStatus="<% =UploadStatus %>";
 // Do stuff based on the value of UploadStatus
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that I can get the value directly in my jQuery function but that doesn't work in my case because the input is in a usercontrol that I'm using many times on the same page. The only difference is that for each usercontrol I send a unique variable UploadStatus....

Comment: Unfortunately NO. var  UploadStatus="<% =UploadStatus %>" would work if I had a single user control on the page. But in case I have the same user control many times on the same page then I would get the value of UploadStatus that was loaded the last.

Comment: And this variable is in page not in controls ?

Comment: So this would take value with respect to controls not the page so you can use it as every control will have its own value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74722/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-gloria).